# List top/bottom ten lines of a word matching in a file

Tags: 9.10, grep

How do I list top or bottom 10 lines from the line that matched the word 'error' in a file.

I'm using `grep 'error' /var/log/logfile.log > errors` to print and save the lines that matched the word 'error' in to the file called 'errors'. How could I change this to suite my requirement?. Anybody has any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Displaying lines before/after/around the match using grep -A, -B and -C

-A is the option which prints the specified N lines after the match as shown below.

-B is the option which prints the specified N lines before the match.

-C is the option which prints the specified N lines before the match. In some occasion you might want the match to be appeared with the lines from both the side. This options shows N lines in both the side(before & after) of match.

Source: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/15-practical-unix-grep-command-examples/ (Also I would recommend you to read the full blog post)

so, the command should be like `grep -C 10 'error'`

Comment: awesome!!!. It's really more than the one what I want and the link is really useful. Again a small thing, a file may have many lines matched the word and is it possible to differentiate/separate with some hashes or spaces or with something.

Comment: Thanks! You can accept the answer as accepted. Regarding your question, are you trying to match selectively? I am not sure if that can be done by `grep` somehow without an example. I would suggest you to ask a different question explaining with an example so that others can help you out.

Comment: @user3215 if you want the first match or the last match, try piping through `head` or `tail`, respectively. Eg `grep -C 10 'error'|head -n 10`

Comment: @djeikyb I think he actually wants to grep the "error" with a certain pattern around that word.

Comment: Eg: after the first 10 lines of from the line contains error, give some space/hashes and then print next 10 lines

Comment: Interesting! I would like to know too.